# Ignore InterruptedException thrown from another thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a class

```
class Foo {
    static void bar() throws InterruptedException {
        // do something
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    static void baz(int a, int b, int c) throws InterruptedException {
        // do something
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Then I simply run it in my main

```
class Main { 
    public static void main() {
        new Thread(Foo::bar).start();
        new Thread(() -> Foo.baz(1, 2, 3)).start();
        new Thread(() -> Foo.baz(1, 2, 3)).start();
    }
}
```

I don't care about the `InterruptedException`. I tried to write a try-catch block, but, obviously, the exception is not caught. Java doesn't allow me to make main() throw either.

How can I simply ignore this exception I don't care at all about? I don't want to write a try-catch block in every thread constructor.

The exception should be thrown at times, but in this specific case I don't care about it.

Comment: Where did you add the try-catch block?

Comment: A Thread is constructed with a Runnable, and a Runnable can't throw a checked exception.

Comment: No, it's not a duplicate, because it's trivial to catch it in a single thread. And it's not trivial to catch it multithreaded without code repetition or bad design.

Comment: The question is a little different, but the accepted answer has a block which addresses your exact situation.

Comment: @marmistrz If you are wondering how to turn off checked exceptions, you can't. There may be a compiler plugin that effectively changes the language you are using to do so though (like Project Lombok).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this solution, I defined an interface `Interruptible`, and a method `ignoreInterruption` which converts an `Interruptible` to a `Runnable`:

```
public class Foo {

  public static void main(String... args) {
    new Thread(ignoreInterruption(Foo::bar)).start();
    new Thread(ignoreInterruption(() -> Foo.baz(1, 2, 3))).start();
  }

  static void bar() throws InterruptedException {
    // do something
    Thread.sleep(1000);
  }

  static void baz(int a, int b, int c) throws InterruptedException {
    // do something
    Thread.sleep(1000);
  }  

  interface Interruptible {
    public void run() throws InterruptedException;
  }

  static Runnable ignoreInterruption(Interruptible interruptible) {
    return () -> { 
      try {
        interruptible.run();
      }
      catch(InterruptedException ie) {
        // ignored
      }
    };
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just catch the exception in your method and ignore it. You never interrupt the thread, so this will be fine.

```
static void bar() {
    try {
    // do something
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ignored) { }
}
```

Comment: Sometimes we want to throw InterruptedException and not ignore it. It's just this one case I want to ignore it